# C++ behaviour when const

Tags: c++

Here's a basic struct (I hope)

```
struct SomeType {
    float a;
    float b;
    float c;
    float d;

    SomeType(float, float, float, float);
};
```

And source

```
SomeType::SomeType(float na, float nb, float nc, float nd) : a(na), b(nb), c(nc), d(nd) {}
```

The I have a class

```
struct SomeClass {
    static const SomeType v;

    SomeClass();
};
```

When I then initialise it

```
const SomeType SomeClass::v(0,0,0,0);
```

My vales become inf or nan or -nan. Anyone seen this before, or know how to fix it?

Edit: Fixed type

Edit: This is quite close to my original example. I multiple classes with similar structure to SomeClass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what code are you seeing those incorrect values?  If it's from something like a constructor of another global variable, remember the [static initialization order fiasco](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.14); `v`'s constructor might just not have run yet.

Put an output statement in the `SomeType` constructor and check whether the output occurs before you see the incorrect values.

Answer (score 3):

```
const SomeClass::v(0,0,0,0);
```

won't compile, since you didn't specify the type of `v`.

Otherwise, this works for me (and should work).

Perhaps you should post a complete, compilable example in one code listing, so we can see what you *really* had in mind.

Comment: Funny enough this is close to my actual example, although I have multiple SomeClass as different Classes. Fixed the type.

Answer (score 1):

Though I didn’t reproduce that exact behavior, the initialization doesn’t specify the type. It should be:

```
const SomeType SomeClass::v(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

After doing this, it works fine.

Comment: Constructor not necessary, as SomeClass is never instantiated.

Comment: True. I instantiated it to test, but I could have accessed `SomeClass::v` directly. Will edit.

Answer (score 1):

Working version:

```
#include <iostream>


struct SomeType {
    float a;
    float b;
    float c;
    float d;

    SomeType(float, float, float, float);

public:

    void print() const
    {
        std::cout << this->a << std::endl;
        std::cout << this->b << std::endl;
        std::cout << this->c << std::endl;
        std::cout << this->d << std::endl;
    }
};

SomeType::SomeType(float na, float nb, float nc, float nd) : a(na), b(nb), c(nc), d(nd) {}

class SomeClass {
    static const SomeType v;

    SomeClass() {}

public:

    static void print()
    {
        v.print();
    }
};

const SomeType SomeClass::v(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f);

void main()
{
    SomeClass::print();
}
```

Output will be:
*0
0
0
0*

Answer (score 1):

Another guy told you were the problem is (static initialization order fiasco). I'll provide you with one solution. You need to get rid of the constructor, so the type will become a POD

```
struct SomeType {
    float a;
    float b;
    float c;
    float d;
};
```

Then you need to initialize it with a braced initializer list that only contains constant expressions (this is *not* limited to only integral constant expressions)

```
const SomeType SomeClass::v = { 0, 0, 0, 0 };
```

Alternatively, but only in the case of zeros, you can leave off the explicit values and just use empty braces

```
const SomeType SomeClass::v = { };
```

In such cases, C++ guarantees you that the values are initialized before any of your code that tries to read it runs.

Answer (score 0):

Since `SomeType  SomeClass::v` is static do you really need to explicitly initialize the members of `SomeType` to zero?

You can avoid the initializing Ctor of SomeType if you are only using it for initializing the members of SomeType to zero (otherwise define the default Ctor SomeType) and just initialize the static member as `const SomeType SomeClass::v;`.